# Carte de séjour waiting

Tags: visa, france

I am a spouse of EU citizen. I have long stay visa up to August 2020. I have got an appointment from *préfecture* for *carte de séjour* but I would like to go in another country for study. Is there any chance that I can request to the *préfecture* to give me *carte de séjour* as early as possible? As I can’t travel with *récipissé*.

Comment: Given the current health crisis and the ensuing backlog, this is highly unlikely. You can try to contact your prefecture (via email or phone), but the prefecture might just tell you that if you choose to leave, you would just need to ask for another EU spousal visa when you wish to return. Prefectures have a reputation of not being the most flexible of offices.

Comment: Would you be traveling with your spouse? For how long? Would you be missing your appointment?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply I am going there for 2 years with my spouse. And also i am not working currently in france. Will they provide me only 2 years of carte de séjour? And if I’ll be not in france then also they will renew my carte? 

And what are the tentative time frame to get the carte de séjour after submitting the documents?

Comment: No my new appointment to submit the documents is in june end. I wants to go there in September.

Comment: @Lynastoke That's a completely different question. The residence card is intended for people who reside in France. I would say that you are supposed to apply for a residence card (or whatever documentation is available) in the country you are going to.

Comment: @Lynastoke You're focusing on the wrong problem, you should be worried about getting the card at all or whether you are entitled to keep it, not whether you can get it quickly. If you want any chance to get one, don't bring that fact to the attention of the *préfecture*! But why do you want a French residence card?

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, no, there is no practical way to speed up processing, even outside of the Covid-19 situation. Even at the best of times, many *préfectures* struggle to meet the legal deadlines for residence cards and residence permits. The most you can do is show up at the appointments they give you and hope they will issue the final card, not another *récépissé*.

Comment: I am going for 2 years study program then i will he return to the France.  What if i go for study without my first carte de séjour? Would france allow me to enter after 2 years or do i need to start the process for long stay visa from the scratch? I have heard that i write the letter to “Prefe “ who is issuing the carte de séjour may be they can help us.

Comment: Moreover i am spouse of EU citizen so i can have legally residency of france. But i would like to know the exact processing time for carte de séjour. My prefacture is L’Haÿ-les-Roses, Val de marne. 

Thank you

Comment: @Lynastoke That's a lot of questions you should ask separetely. I don't think writing to the *préfet* is likely to achieve anything. Where have you read this?

Comment: @Lynastoke I cannot predict the exact processing time, I already told you the most important thing. But having the card wouldn't legally change your position. You indeed have a right to reside in France with your spouse but the logic of the system is that you should apply for the relevant *carte de séjour* when you want to reside in France, not two years in advance. For now, you should apply for a residence card in the country where you will study.

Comment: In two years from now, if you hold a residence card from another EU country, I think you should be able to apply for the French residence card directly from within the country. If you don't and you find yourself outside the EU, yes, you will may have to restart the long-stay visa process from scratch.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. 
Yes i will be applying residence card of that country where i will be studying but i don’t want to leave the rights of france residency so for that reason i would like to go there with French Residence card.

Comment: @Lynastoke as the spouse of an EU citizen you can always enter France with your spouse or when your spouse is in France.  You don't really need the residence card for much of anything.  If you leave without the *recipissé,* your application for a residence card is likely to be treated as abandoned, which will be an inconvenience because you'll have to start over from the beginning when you return, but it won't jeopardize your right to enter or reside in France.

Comment: Yeah that’s right that i do have a legal rights to stay in france with my spouse but i have a long stay visa valid until August 2020. And i am planning to go in September. So if i want to come back after 2 years from the Non EU country do i need to again apply for the Long stay visa?

Comment: @Lynastoke It depends on your exact status at that time, in particular whether you hold a residence card from another EU country. If you take up residence in a non-EU country in the meantime and nothing else exempts you from the visa requirement, you may have to apply for a visa again (although, as the spouse of an EU citizen, this process should be facilitated as well). But that's an entirely separate question, I would invite you to post it as such, providing as many details as possible and not making too many assumptions.